# Custom UINavigationBar gradient background and image in logo

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have some problems with inheriting UINavigationBar.
First of all, I have to use the same class in multiple UINavigationBar, since everything is embedded in UITabBar. So I have a UITabBar connected to 5 different UINavigationBar.
All these UINavigationBars should have a gradient background and an image as title. I tried inheriting and setting this class to each of them, but it does not work.

```
class NavBar: UINavigationBar {

func setupNavBar(){
    self.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
    self.topItem?.titleView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    self.setNeedsLayout()
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.setupNavBar()
}
```

}

I have tried different combinations, but in most of them I cannot see the image. Also it happened to have a different behavior by calling the same class in different UINavigationBar, for instance in the first tab I can see the gradient, but if I change it then it is not there.
Please help me to solve this by using the subclass, I do not want to put the code in controllers.
Extra: I would also like to fill the status bar with gradient, but I can only fill static color

Comment: When I test your code I get the image (I've used a system image as I dont have the "image" in my files which your referencing to) but, I do not get the gradient like you do.

Comment: @Demented07 try to embed two NavBars in a UITabBarController, you will see that in the others tab you can see the gradient and not the image lol (maybe you have to change the code a little, because I tried different options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by inheriting UITabBarController instead and putting gradient as backgroundImage

```
class NavBarController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
        self.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        var bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        bounds.size.height += self.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        bounds.origin.y -= self.view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black, UIColor.white]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)
    }
    
    func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer.frame.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return outputImage!
    }
}
```